# Python Try: Except: inside a function(a, b, c)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I use a try: except: inside a print like this?

```
print "variable content: %s" % ( try: my_var  except: "empty" )
```

I am looking for a more pythonic way than doing this before the print.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you try to use it? could your variable be undefined? Which possible values could it have?

Comment: Why would `my_var` raise an exception? Don't you have a more complicated expression there?

Comment: Short answer: no you cannot

Comment: In any case, I feel like it's bad design to have a variable that's sometimes created and sometimes not. You could just do `my_var = "empty"` at the beginning of your function, and then your `print` would never raise an exception, whether or not `my_var` gets a real value later.

Comment: What does `my_var` stand for? If it's a variable (as implied by the name), then the question at hand makes little sense.

Comment: Actually, there is actually some discussion about implementing this in future versions of Python using syntax not very different from yours. I don't know the final outcome, though.

Comment: @Kevin Actually the my_var is provided by Amazon's AWS API "boto". Especially for the scheduled downtimes. If those are forever, the endTime is of type None. But a very good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in one line with try, but you can do it with a ternary operator:

```
print "my var's content: %s" %( my_var if my_var != "" else "blank" )
```

Replace the test to meet your conditions more accurately.

Comment: a more concise way is: `% str(my_var or 'blank')`

Answer (score 0):

There is no single-line solution to catch exceptions. Here is a workaround:

```
try:
  print_var = ...my_var...
except:
  print_var = "empty"
print "variable content: %s" % print_var
```

Comment: Might as well print `my_var` in the try/except directly :-)

Comment: Wouldn't `print_var` be recognized only inside the scope of each clause (hence, not recognized outside the `try/except` block)?

Comment: @barakmanos - In Python, only functions, classes, and modules have scope (module scope is the global scope).  Every other code structure however, such as if-statements, loops, and `try/except` blocks, makes the variables that were created inside it accessible to the code below it in the current scope.